# Eclipse Errors after I Export as Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After I exported my project, I got a bunch of errors.

They are all "cannot be resolved to a type" and "cannot be resolved to a variable" errors, and none of them were there before I exported the project

Please help me if you know how to fix this or have any idea.

Comment: It sounds like you may have exported a project, and then imported it to another eclipse installation.  If this is the case, perhaps the project has dependencies that were other projects that you didn't export?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided a valid JRE or JDK path in the Java Build Path of your project. Right-click on your project, select Properties > and then Java Build Path.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? sorry i'm relatively new at this.

Comment: every error just says
something could not be defined to a type
and
Something could not be defined to a variable

Those are the only two errors I'm getting. But like a hundred times each.